# Capacitor put the wrong way by manufacturer - is this on purpose or is this a problem?

Tags: capacitor, radio, polarity

I am about to change the electrolytic capacitors of a Soviet Selena radio from 1988. I noticed that a few of the capacitors are put with the oposite polarization in respect to the board, e.g. this one (the plus side of the cap is opposite to the plus side on the board):
[image]

And here another 2 capacitors that I think of being put in the correct way, or at least they are put in the opposite way to the cap from the above image:
[image]
([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbAqc.jpg))

I found a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfvJ9bBEmEA) in Russian discussing this, but I don't understand out of it if this is a problem and what you are supposed to do.

My questions:

1. Am I right that the show capacitor is put wrongly?
2. Is this done on purpose by the manufacturer? If yes, why?
3. When I insert the new capacitors should I put them as indicated on the board or should I stick to the orientation of the original
   capacitors, even if it is wrong?

FYI, a top view of the whole radio:
[image]

Comment: Isn’t the symbol on the capacitor indicatiing that the outer shell is positive?  Therefore they look the correct way to me.

Comment: @HandyHowie Thanks, I included a picture from another 2 capacitors having the opposite orientation to the first one. How would you explain their orientation?

Comment: Is the radio functional in its present state? If so, I would power it up and measure the bias across the capacitors in order to be sure of the polarity.

Comment: @DaveTweed The radio works, but the volume is very, very low. The suggestion I received was to change all the electrolytic capacitors, some of them have indeed leaked. Can I measure this bias just with a multi meter? My knowledge of electronics is only from the last years of high school

Comment: Yes, a multimeter should work. Also, if the electrolytics in question are being used as audio coupling capacitors (consistent with the problem you're having), it's possible that the polarity doesn't matter -- there might be no significant DC bias across them.

Comment: Just a side note that rarely, the PCB can be labeled wrong. Of course production units are "fixed" before being shipped, but I've seen on a few occasions where the silkscreen print is just plain wrong.